# Why Comment's Reference Text Return null in Interop.Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` (in C#) to work with word (word 2013)

I Addes some comments to my doc, and now i want to read comment's reference text (`Range.Comments[0].Reference.Text`) but it is always null.

Also i look to range start & range end position and it seems range position is at end of the reference and it is always on step position (like 271 to 272)

How can get the correct range of comment reference?

Example of code:

```
var comments = Doc.Comments;
foreach (var comment in comments)
{
    //this variable is always null :(
    var commentRefText = comment.Reference.Text;
}
```

**Solved:**

with using of `comment.Scope.Text` the referenced text returned.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could attach a sample doc and provide a [mcve] reproducing the issue.

Comment: add simple of my code